# inline with binding with an observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a model property defined as follows:

```
function Field(name, size, type){
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.size = ko.observable(size);
    this.type = ko.observable(type);
    this.map = ko.observable();
}
```

I have an observable array (`fields`) defined which is an array of the above object. On ui interaction the `map` property of the Field object will get associated with another object. It is a `Header` object with properties `headerName` and `index`.

I am trying to bind the fields as follows:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <li class="form-inline">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span> -> 
        <span data-bind="text: map.headerName"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it was unsuccessful: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/sENA8/2/

Tried it as follows:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <li class="form-inline">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span> -> 
        <span data-bind="with: map"><span data-bind="headerName"></span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Still doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/sENA8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this without using the `with` binding

```
<span data-bind="text: map() && map().headerName"></span>
```

Note you need the `()` after the `map` to get its value and using the  `map() &&` make sure that the expression won't be evaluated unless `map` is set to some value.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLUke/).

Of course using the `with` binding is more elegant and proper solution for handling these use cases, and you've almost made it, you've just forgotten the `text` in your inner binding expression:

```
<span data-bind="with: map"><span data-bind="text: headerName"></span></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gCpL/).

Comment: I wonder why Knockout does not throw an exception when you supply a data-bind like that. It would be much easier to find the problem and fix the missing "text:"